# Combobox not loading displaying store data - Ext JS

Tags: extjs, model, combobox, store

No matter what I try, I cannot get my combobox to display a single field from my store.

Here's my code:

store/Criteria_1.js

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Critera_1', { //temp store
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.Criteria1',
    storeId: 'search_criteria_1',
    fields: ['TECH_NAME', 'KBE_ID', 'KBE_NAME'],
    data : [
        { TECH_NAME: 'TECH_NAME' },
        { KBE_ID: 'KBE_ID' },
        { KBE_NAME: 'KBE_NAME' }
    ];
});
```

model/Criteria_1.js

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Criteria_1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'TECH_NAME', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'KBE_ID', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'KBE_NAME', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

And here's where I'm trying to call it, app.js:

```
{ xtype: 'combobox', padding: 5,   id: 'criteria_1_dropdown', store: Ext.StoreManager.get('Criteria_1'), displayField: 'KBE_ID' },
```

I don't want to use a proxy just yet either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define `fields` in your store if you are using a `Model`.  Also. the `data` you have in your store is most likely not what you are looking for.  You have 3 different records, each with only one of your fields populated.  You probably want this:

```
data : [
    { 
        TECH_NAME: 'TECH_NAME',
        KBE_ID: 'KBE_ID',
        KBE_NAME: 'KBE_NAME' 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it looking at this example from the Extjs 5 documentation: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-combos

You have a few things different. Try this:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Criterion', { // the model name should be singular; it refers to only one entry)
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       'TECH_NAME',
       'KBE_ID',
       'KBE_NAME'
    ]
});

Ext.define('AM.store.Critera_1', { //temp store
    extend:'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    model: 'AM.model.Criterion',
    storeId: 'search_criteria_1',
    data : [
        [ 'TECH_NAME_ONE', 'KBE_ID_ONE', 'KBE_NAME_ONE' ]
    ];
});
```

Finally:

```
{ 
    xtype: 'combobox', 
    padding: 5,   
    id: 'criteria_1_dropdown', 
    store: { type:'search_criteria_1' }, 
    displayField: 'KBE_ID',
    queryMode:'local'
}
```

Pay attention to `queryMode:'local'`. I adapted my working code to your example without testing.

I hope it helps.